# How to make a function for dataframe that checks if big tuple contains all the elements of the small one?

Tags: python, pandas

After 24 hours of meaningless tries I don't have another word than "Help!"
I have the dataframe contains 2 columns: 'uid' int, 'course_id' as a tuple of 2 or more other ids (int).

| uid | course_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | (1,2) |
| 2 | (1,2) |
| 3 | (1,3) |
| 4 | (1,2,3) |
| 5 | (2,3) |

A kind of this but with 13k of rows. Although original df where I have ungrouped lines uid-course_id. Like

| uid | course_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 |

etc.
I need another dataframe with all unique pairs of course_id and number of users that have these pairs in the second column. Like this but bigger (4k of rows):

| pair | users |
| --- | --- |
| (1,2) | 3 |
| (1,3) | 2 |
| (2,3) | 2 |

I can make a column of all unique pairs but I have no idea how to count users. The closest function was

```
def user_count(pair):
        total_users = df[
            np.isin(df['course_id'], pair)
        ].groupby(
            'uid', as_index=False
        ).filter(
            lambda x: len(x)==2
        ).groupby(
            'course_id', as_index=False
        ).count()['uid'][0]
        return total_users
```

for original dataframe and in works when I give an exact tuple, but it doesn't work with df.apply(user_count).
Is it easier to use the original df or filtered and combined to tuples? And how can I count all the users with every pair?

Comment: Is it safe to assume that the tuple `(1, 2)` is the same as `(2, 1)`?

Comment: @It_is_Chris yep, it's totally the same

Comment: @alex Can the `uid` column contains duplicated entries?

Comment: @ShubhamSharma original dataframe with 1 uid & 1 course_id - yes. 1 uid can have up to 7 courses as I remember, so it'll be in the df 7 times. The combined df with tuples - no, unique uid and the tuple of unique course_ids

Comment: @Alex So i guess you have used something like `df.groupby('uid').agg(tuple)` to obtain the tuple pairs from the original dataframe, Right? Is it okay if we used your original dataframe as a starting point this will save you from the expensive computation of calculating `df.groupby('uid').agg(tuple)` if its not really required?

Comment: @ShubhamSharma that's how I made the combined df (the first table in my question) :D

`pair_list = []
for i in df_mcid.resource_id:
    pair_list.append(list(itertools.combinations(i,2)))
pair_list = list(set(itertools.chain(*pair_list)))`

Here is what I have for unique pairs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Setup

```
>>> df # original df

    uid course_id
0     1         1
1     1         2
2     2         1
3     2         2
4     3         1
5     3         3
6     4         1
7     4         2
8     4         3
9     5         2
10    5         3
```

#### Solution

```
from itertools import combinations

onehot = pd.get_dummies(df['course_id'])\
           .set_index(df['uid']).sum(level=0)

cnt = {}
for c in combinations(onehot, r=2):
    cnt[c] = onehot[[*c]].ge(1).all(1).sum()

counts = pd.DataFrame(cnt.items(), columns=['pairs', 'count'])
```

#### Explanations

One hot encode the `couse_id` column to create indicator variables for each unique value in `course_id`, then reduce the encoded variables along `axis=0` by taking `sum` on `level=0`

```
>>> onehot

     1  2  3
uid         
1    1  1  0
2    1  1  0
3    1  0  1
4    1  1  1
5    0  1  1
```

Now iterate over all the pairs obtain from the combinations of unique values in `course_id` column, and for each pair calculate the number of rows in the onehot encoded dataframe where these pairs are present

```
>>> cnt

{(1, 2): 3, (1, 3): 2, (2, 3): 2}
```

Now create a new dataframe from the above dictionary which contains the counts of unique users for every possible combination of values in `course_id`

```
>>> counts

    pairs  count
0  (1, 2)      3
1  (1, 3)      2
2  (2, 3)      2
```

Comment: Hmm... It could work, I can try it. Isn't it too complicated if I have 13k unique uids and 1100 courses?

Comment: @Alex Not sure about the complexness but here we are starting from your original dataframe which save the intermediate step of aggregating the dataframe to calculate the tuples.. you can try the solution.

Comment: I've tried it. Yep, it works well and even faster then previous answer! A bit more of coding but faster :)
You're great, man, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already have a column of all unique pairs, here is a way you can count users:

You can use [`.map()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) and count number of items in `pair` as subset of `course_id`, as follows:

```
df2['users'] = df2['pair'].map(lambda x: len([y for y in df1['course_id'].values if set(x).issubset(y)]))


print(df2)

     pair  users
0  (1, 2)      3
1  (1, 3)      2
2  (2, 3)      2
```

One caveat of this solution maybe on the performance issue for large number of rows.  I haven't tested it out yet.  You may just try and see if it can fulfill your system performance consideration.